# CCMoveTo doesn't move CCSprite to the right position in cocos2d-x-2.1.5

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I have strange behavior when using `CCMoveTo` to move Sprite A to position of Sprite B.
Sprite A and B are children of Sprite C which is child of Sprite D.
All anchorpoints are (0,0).

What I have in code:

```
D->addChild(C,1);
C->addChild(A,1);
C->addChild(A,1);
CCPoint BOriginalPos = B->getPosition();  //this is the sprite where i want to move sprite A to  , which is : x160.000000 ,y:81.000000
CCMoveTo* AMoveToB = CCMoveTo::create(0.3f,BOriginalPos );
CCSequence* AMovesToBSequence = CCSequence::create(AMoveToB , NULL);
A->runAction(AMovesToBSequence);
```

But when I log print the A position I get: **x187.925095, y:81.000000**
and I expect it to be: **x160.000000, y:81.000000** as B
It looks like the animation action moves A in the world space X and Y and not to the Node space that is the position that is relative to to Sprite C.

But how can I fix this? Am I doing wrong here?

Comment: could you debug this part of code to see if it's been called more than one time?

Comment: Its running another movement?

Comment: its called from one place , and there is no other movment

Comment: Have you found any fix to this yet? Wondering why this is happening to me as well.

Comment: yeah moved to version 3.3